# Никак не могу понять каким образом можно подключить слайдер в angular?

Tags: javascript, angular2, frontend

Коллеги здравствуйте. 
Очень нуждаюсь в помощи, я новичок в ангуляре, я пишу проект с использованием этого фреймворка но столкнулся с проблемой которую уже несколько часов не могу решить, я делаю верстку и разделяю его на компоненты, всё шло хорошо пока не дошёл до момента сделать вертикальный слайдер, не могу понять что я делаю неправильно, мне нравиться fullpage.js но я использовал и slick.

Что я делаю? 
Я копирую html/css отсюда: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/CreativeSeo33/pen/bVdgxr) и вкладываю в мой созданный новый компонент, js я сохраняю отдельно в папке assets/js как slider.js. 
Jquery/Файлы самого fullpage.js и тд я подключаю в заглавном index.html, всё я это делаю но у меня ничего не работает. Я выводил их через app.component.html в заглавном, вот так.

```
<div class="inner">
<header></header> - другой компонент 
<slider></slider> - мой слайдер(тот который я вывожу)
</div>
```

Пожалуйста опишите как правильно нужно подключать или скачивать, или в ангуляре как то по другому это всё работает буду рад видеоурокам по этой теме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну начнем с того, что `<slider></slider>` - это компонент. Если ты просто копируешь в assets, то это не заработает. Необходимо создать компонент, его оформить и подключить к AppModule. На сайте все рассказано. Потому как скорее всего не происходит инициализации самого слайдера. Могу посоветовать добавить к SliderComponent ngOnInit - событие, происходящее при инициализации компонента и туда переписать код на ts. Если необходимо объявить JQuery то просто в index.html подключи как обычно подключаешь свои либы, а в компоненте перед декоратором `@Component` вставь `declare let $: any;`, тогда ты сможешь вызывать JQuery в компоненте. Ну и просто поищи аналоги, написанные уже на ANgular (если совсем лень).